# AngularJS routing to Public page (e.g. signup)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, url-routing, angular-routing

I have a problem with Angular.js (and maybe express) routing. After a while I managed to fix the routing for normal subpages, but now I want to add some public accessbale pages like `signup`, `password-lost/reset` etc. But everytime I visit `http://127.0.0.1/signup` I get redirected to `http://127.0.0.1/login`.

Here's my `app.js` (angular routing)

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
$routeProvider.when('/login', {templateUrl: 'views/login.html', controller: 'LoginCtrl'})
.when('/password-reset/:reset', { templateUrl: 'views/password-lost/password-reset.html', controller: 'LoginCtrl' })
.when('/signup', { templateUrl: 'views/signup.html', controller: 'SignupCtrl' })
.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
```

my `server.js` (express routing)

```
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
   // res.sendfile(__dirname + '/public/index.html'); I tried this as well, but it has the same effect
   res.redirect('/#' + req.originalUrl);
});
```

`req.originalUrl` is filled with the correct view, e.g. `/signup`.

Since my views are inside `/public/views` I also tried

```
res.redirect('/#/views/' + req.originalUrl);
```

But it has the same effect.

has anyone an idea where and why my route changes from `/signup` to `/login`?

Answer (score 0):

I use [angular-fullstack](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack) yeoman boilerplate. This is how they solve this problem:

```js
// All other routes to use Angular routing in app/scripts/app.js
app.route('/partials/*')
   .get(index.partials);
app.route('/*')
  .get(index.index); //Use the controller which renders your index.html
```

Now all your routes will render index controller first delegating routing to Angular.

Answer (score 0):

ok, that was a dumb mistake on my part. I had a redirect to `/login` inside my application -.-